# Paquetes y módulos en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

*Hola me gustaría saber como puedo resolver el asunto de importación de archivos  entre carpetas *

Les muestro mi directorio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada carpeta contiene su respectivo **init**.py como se ve en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que pretendo es poder usar lo que 
esta en el archivo a.py en el archivo b.py,

[y viceversa también]

que como se ve están en diferentes carpetas
para 
 después usarlo en el archivo main.py
estoy usando Windows 10

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si tu importas algo de **a.py** en **b.py** y a la misma vez de **b.py** en **a.py** vas a tener problemas ya que va a ver dependencia circular.

Comment: Ok me queda claro @eyllanesc lo demas cual seria la posible solucion

Comment: Okay, si te queda claro entonces estas ante un mal diseño, rediseñalo, esa es la solución.